# TEXTURE and POINT at the same time in WebGL

Tags: textures, webgl, point

I would like to make WebGL application which includes gl.POINTS rendering along with gl.TEXTURE.  Is it possible to create a shader which enables point rendering and texture at the same time?

Comment: Sorry. I need to explain more in detail.  I am creating a fireworks simulation at:

http://www.keiyuasa.com/index_circular.html

Here, fireworks are rendered with gl.POINTS and the ring on the ground is rendered with gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP.  I can render these two at the same time.

However, I cannot add polygons with textures while fireworks are rendered as gl.POINTS.  However, I cannot render gl.POINTS and gl.TEXTURE at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by

> enables point rendering and texture at the same time

Vertex shader put set of simple shapes (set of triangles or set of points) on canvas one by one. Then for each pixel that is covered by one shape fragment shader set new color.

If you want to draw image on canvas, you must establish shape/shapes (best options are one point or two triangles) and map texture on the shape/shapes.

Example of points with textures:
http://math.hws.edu/~sv6529/cs424/lab4/points.html

Comment: Thank you, Entity,

As I wrote above, I would like to render Polygons and points on the same screen.  I can render Points (with gl.POINTS) and polygons (with gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP).  However, if I try to map a texture to the polygons, I cannot render both gl.POINTS and gl.TEXTURE.

Comment: Link is broken.